# CSS column property

Tags: css

So I noticed the column property doesn't work in internet explorer so I tried finding alternate ways to create columns, I found a way to do it with tables, but that looks a bit clunky. Is there a way to use divs and create two vertical columns splitting the page?

Comment: Please add some sample HTML and CSS so we can see what you've tried and advise how to fix it.

Comment: If a table or floats (or positioning) is a solution, as you have expressed, then the question was not really about the CSS `columns` property (and there is no `column` property). Multicolumn layout, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/, is about *flowing* content into multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with floats. e.g.:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="col1">Column1</div>
<div class="col2">Column2</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.col1 { width: 50%; height:100px; float:left; background:#ddd}
.col2 { width: 50%; height:100px; float:left; background:#777}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/AfgAG/9/

Comment: on a 2 column layout with enough horizontal space on the page, it doesn't have to be float:right. Both can be float:left

Comment: It may work, but (in my opinion) programming is about clarity. The more obvious code is about what it is trying to do, it is easier to understand and the easier it is to debug!

Comment: 2x float:left's generally work better IMO. They hug each other, and you can control the space between them easily as well. e.g, in my example, if you changed one of the widths to 40%, and col2 to float:right, you'll see a big gap.

Comment: That's cool, I never knew that! And if you wanted to do more columns, I assume you could do more float:left's?

Comment: Thanks! I had to change it to float right and float left but other than that, it worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You can put two `div` tags next to each other and give one the `float:left` CSS property, and the other `float:right`. Both of those divs must be at the same level in your DOM tree. What I mean by that: basically, both div tags must be 'next' to each other when you write the HTML, so that one is not inside of a tag that the other is not. For example:

`<div> stuff </div> <div> more stuff </div>` is okay, but

`<div> stuff </div> <div> <div> more stuff </div> </div>` would require the outer div tags to be labeled with `float:left` or `float:right`, not the inner div that directly contains 'more stuff'.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `column-count` although not in IE before 10. With prefixes it works in everything else.

Is `float` not working for you?